# Hadoop - HDInsight append to HDFS or upload the extra file?

Tags: file, hadoop, append, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to learn HDInsight and Hadoop.

What is the advantage of appending to a file in HDFS instead of copying the extra data file to the same data folder in HDFS?

More clearly, from my single node machine, I uploaded my data file to HDFS. Now if I need to add extra data to this file, I can use "append" method, right? Or can I just send the new extra file to HDFS under the same input folder? So that it will have multiple files as input files.

Is there any disadvantage over appending the extra data to the HDFS file? As I understand correctly, since data blocks are 64 MB or 128 MB, I would just have an extra data block right?

Let's say my first input file is 75 MB, and I would have two blocks of data 64 MB and 11 MB, and if I added the new file (75 MB) without appending, then I would have 4 blocks of sizes: 64 MB, 11 MB, 64 MB and 11 MB. If I use append method, then I would have 3 blocks of sizes: 64 MB, 64 MB and 22 MB.

Do I understand correctly? Is the disadvantage of the one more data block very big issue?

Comment: Have you really tried it yourself. AFAIK, HDInsight uses Apache Hadoop-1.0.3. and hadoop-1.x series doesn't support appends. See this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8230

Comment: I didn't try appending with HDInsight or with Hadoop. Thanks for the link. It looks it is not possible yet. But I came across windows hdfs library WinHdfsManaged, they are mentioning appending. It is not clear to me though.